# Char outputting random characters at the end of the sentence

Tags: c++, arrays, char, c-strings

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void crypt(char* sMsg)
{
    cout << "Original Message: '" << sMsg << "'" << endl;

    int length = strlen(sMsg);
    char sMsg_Crypt[3][length];
    /*  sMsg_Cryp[3]
        [0] CRYPT LETTERS, ASCII + 3
        [1] INVERT CHAR
        [2] HALF+ OF SENTENCE, ASCII - 1
    */
    
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha((int)sMsg[i]))
            sMsg_Crypt[0][i] = sMsg[i] + 3; // DO ASCII + 3
        else
            sMsg_Crypt[0][i] = sMsg[i];
    }

    cout << "Crypt[0]: '" << sMsg_Crypt[0] << "'" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char sMsg[256];
    cin.getline(sMsg,256);
    crypt(sMsg);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

> Hello World! Testing the Cryptography...

Output:

> Original Message: 'Hello World! Testing the Cryptography...'
>
> Crypt[0]: 'Khoor Zruog! Whvwlqj wkh Fu|swrjudsk|...Çi­o'

Why this `Çi­o` is comming out??

Comment: Because your char-arrays are not null-terminated. And they are also non-standard C++, better use `std::string`.

Comment: Where's your null-terminator?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, see [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters variable length arrays like this

```
int length = strlen(sMsg);
char sMsg_Crypt[3][length];
```

is not a standard C++ feature.

You could use at least an array of objects of the type `std::string` like for example

```
std::string sMsg_Crypt[3];
```

Nevertheless the problem is that the array `sMsg_Crypt[0]` dies not contain a string. That is you forgot to append inserted characters in the array with the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

You could write after the for loop

```
sMsg_Crypt[0][length] = '\0';
```

provided that the array (if the compiler supports VLA) is declared like

```
char sMsg_Crypt[3][length+1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can't define a static `char` array like this: `char sMsg_Crypt[3][length];`. That is because the `length` is not a `const` type, meaning the size of the array will be `sMsg_Crypt[3][0]` (this is because the size is not known at compile time). In MSVC, it'll flag an error (by IntelliSense). Since you know the size beforehand (256), you can replace the `length` with 256.

The second fact is that you're using C++ and you have access to `std::string`. So without using a char buffer,  use `std::string` instead. It would look something like this: `std::string sMsg_Crypt[3];`

The last fact is that, for a string to be read correctly, it needs to be null-terminated ('\0' at the end). This means that the ending character must be '\0'. In the case of `std::string`, it does it for you.

Comment: I knw what you mean. You know what you mean. But be careful with static. It's a heavily overloaded term and means something very different in C++. Use Automatic instead.